# simple_form not detecting triggered validations for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, nested-attributes

I have a model called "Treating". It's essentially a meeting proposal with a requestor and a requestee, but also an (1) :intro (2) :proposed_venue (3) :proposed_date (4) :proposed_time.

These four attributes (three of which are nested attributes) appear as fields on a form. All of the attributes have validates_presence_of validations, but only the :intro field is being validated by the simple_form gem I have installed (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). This must be because only the :intro attribute (out of the four above) is an attribute of the Treating model. A Treating has many proposed venues through the Venue model, and many proposed dates and proposed times through the TDateTime model.

The odd thing is that I can see validations are being triggered by Active Record for all four attributes if they are all blank. It's just that simple_form is not highlighting their blank fields red with a "can't be blank" notice.

To verify this, I added an "@treating.errors.full_messages..." line to my form, which is appropriately returning four errors if there are four blank fields (screenshot at bottom):

```
<% if @treating.errors.any? %>

<ul>
  <% @treating.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3><%= @user.first_name + " " + @user.last_name[0] + "." %></h3>
    <p>
      <% if @user.picture_url %>
        <%= image_tag(@user.picture_url, :size => "30x30") %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag('smiley_small.png', :size => "30x30") %>
      <% end %> 
      <%= @user.headline %>
    </p>
  </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <form action="#" class="span12">
          <label for="treating-message"><h5>Introduce yourself to <%= @user.first_name %> (sample introductions):</h5></label>

          <%= f.hidden_field :requestee_id %>

          <%= f.label :intro, "Introduce yourself to " + @user.first_name + ":" %>
          <%= f.input :intro %>

          <%= f.simple_fields_for :t_date_times_attributes, :validate => { :presence => true } do |t_date_time| %>
            <%= t_date_time.simple_fields_for :"0" do |zero| %>  
              <%= zero.input :date, :input_html => { :value => params[:treating][:t_date_times_attributes][:'0'][:date] } %>
              <%= zero.input :time, :input_html => { :value => params[:treating][:t_date_times_attributes][:'0'][:time] } %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <input class="bigdrop" id="e7" placeholder="Pick a venue with foursquare..." name="proposed_venue[foursquare_id]" />

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="field">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <%= f.submit "Send", id: "send-button" %>
        </div>
    </div>

<% else %>

<ul>
<% @treating.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li>* <%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>

  <div id="modal-treating" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3><%= @user.first_name + " " + @user.last_name[0] + "." %></h3>
    <p>
      <% if @user.picture_url %>
        <%= image_tag(@user.picture_url, :size => "30x30") %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag('smiley_small.png', :size => "30x30") %>
      <% end %> 
      <%= @user.headline %>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <form action="#" class="span12">
        <label for="treating-message"><h5>Introduce yourself to <%= @user.first_name %> (sample introductions):</h5></label>

        <%= f.hidden_field :requestee_id %>

          <%= f.label :intro, "Introduce yourself to " + @user.first_name + ":" %>
          <%= f.input :intro %>

          <div class="control-group">
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :t_date_times_attributes, :validate => { :presence => true } do |t_date_time| %>
              <%= t_date_time.simple_fields_for :"0", :validate => { :presence => true } do |zero| %>
                <%= zero.input :date, :validate => { :presence => true } %>
                <%= zero.input :time, :validate => { :presence => true } %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>            

      <input class="bigdrop" id="e7" placeholder="Pick a venue with foursquare..." name="proposed_venue[foursquare_id]" />

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="field">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
      <%= f.submit "Send", id: "send-button" %>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>

<% end %>
```

[image]
[image]

(All fields should be highlighted red in accordance with the error messages at the top of the page, but only the intro field is [likely because it is the only non-nested attribute]).

Although I thought this whole problem may have been an issue with Ajax (notice remote true at the top of my form), it isn't. I had the same results reloading a new page/submitting blank fields.

As a side note, you can also see in the picture that my bottom field, proposed venue, loses its styling on the Ajax reload (the entire form actually loses all of its styling). This may be another question entirely, but if anyone has any thoughts about why css/js would be dropped on an ajax modal form reload, I'd be happy to know.

I've been beating my head against this for too long now and thought I'd seek help from SO!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will be much easier if you make this all one form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @treating do %>
  <%= fields_for :t_date_times do %>
    <% # etc... %>
```

Anytime you're writing your own form tags...you're gonna have a bad time. This way SimpleForm can work out what objects it should be pulling errors from. Otherwise it doesn't really have any way of knowing.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 is the canonical great example - it works just the same with SimpleForm.